# Can not get touch event when UIView outside of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

We have a table cell and a drop down list(which customized via table view). the problem is when we add drop down list to a table cell content view, and open it, drop down list cannot get touch event.

We tried hit test, but it cannot get drop down view.

It seems that the drop down list is floating when it is opened.

Here are 2 screen shots for this.
first screen shot before drop down list is clicked:
[image]

Second screen shot when drop down list is clicked:
 [image]

Comment: You are just adding additional cells to that section to get the drop down right?

Comment: the below answer is really for answering your comments: no, "please select ownership" is a table view and added to another table view cell.

"please select ownership" is a dropdown control which wrap via a table view, when click it, it will insert additional cells dynamically.

Comment: any suggestions here? Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

no, "please select ownership" is a table view and added to another table view cell.

"please select ownership" is a dropdown control which wrap via a table view, when click it, it will insert additional cells dynamically.